# How to have sections of image and text in a responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using the following css to have 8 sections of text and image. I need to fix the size of the boxes. However, based on current design, the size of boxes is based on their content, so if a box has short content it will be smaller than a box with longer content.

**CSS**

```
.test{
  min-width:80%;
  max-width:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.test ul {
  text-align:center;
}

.test ul li{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:left;
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 23%;
  min-height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid orange ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:1%;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.test li p{overflow: hidden; margin: 10px;}
.test p + p{clear: both;}
.test li p img{float: right; margin-right:10px;}
.test h2{margin-left: 2.2%;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
<h2>This is the test of 8 sections</h2>
    <ul>
  <li><p>
    <img src="../img/d.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    test tfdfdf dfdf<br/>
    454 4545 45<br/>
    32434 34234
</p>
<p>
  blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>

</p></li>
<li><p>
    <img src="../img/d.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    test tfdfdf dfdf<br/>
    454 4545 45<br/>
    32434 34234
</p>
<p>
   blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>

</p></li>
<li><p>
    <img src="../img/d.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    test tfdfdf dfdf<br/>
    454 454545 215<br/>
    32434 34234
</p>
<p>blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>
</p></li>
<li><p>
    <img src="../img/d.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    test tfdfdf dfdf<br/>
    45456 5565<br/>
    32434 34234
</p>
<p>blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>

</p></li>
 <li><p>
    <img src="../img/d.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    test tfdfdf dfdf<br/>
    454 4545 45<br/>
    32434 34234
</p>
<p>
   blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>

</p></li>
 <li><p>
    <img src="../img/e.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    Test test<br/>
    3434 343434 34343<br/>
    Test new Test
</p>
<p>blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</br>
</p></li>
<li><p>
    <img src="../img/f.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
   <b>fdgfg dfgg fdg</b><br/>
     435345 435345<br/>
    Gladstone Qld
</p>
<p> blah blah blah Text Here <br/>See more …
</p>
  </li>
  <li><p>
    <img src="../img/g.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    Test Test is test<br/>
   444 5444 4444<br/>
   Test test
</p>
<p>
   blah blah blah Text Here <br/> See more …
</p>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>   <!-- test -->
```

**JsFiddle** [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/akrfq6vw/)

Comment: So far all the boxes seem to be the same size. Can you show us the problem. You can use this pen as a testing environment http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYaeGL

Comment: @LOTUSMS please click on the JSFiddle link at the bottom of the question to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make fix height for Boxes then make vertical scroll for the boxes with max-height
So,Your content won't get hide and box will be of fixed height
Try it out

```
.test ul li{
max-height: 250px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```